# merging two dataset with python

Tags: python, merge

first dataset: dim(d)=(70856886 12), Second dataset: dim(e)=(354 6)
both data set have common variable which is subject and I want to merge both dataset by subject, I used this code by python:

```
# Merging both dataset:
data=pd.merge(d, e, on='subject')
```

When I do that I lost some data set my dim of my new merging dataset is 62611728
my question is why I am losing those observation?? [70856886- 62611728= 8245158]

Comment: By default [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) does an _inner_ join (`how='inner'`). That means: _use intersection of keys from both frames_. So, most likely, some keys don't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, `pd.merge()` "Merge[s] DataFrame or named Series objects with a database-style join."

In general, it's a good idea to try something on a small dataset to see if you understand its function correctly and then to apply it to a large dataset.

Here's an example for `pd.merge()`:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {'subject': 'a', 'value': 1},
    {'subject': 'a', 'value': 2},
    {'subject': 'b', 'value': 3},
    {'subject': 'c', 'value': 4},
    {'subject': 'c', 'value': 5},
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {'subject': 'a', 'other': 6},
    {'subject': 'b', 'other': 7},
    {'subject': 'b', 'other': 8},
    {'subject': 'd', 'other': 9}
])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='subject')
print(df)
```

What output do you expect? It should be this:

```
  subject  value  other
0       a      1      6
1       a      2      6
2       b      3      7
3       b      3      8
```

In your case, we can only assume that, when combined, only 62611728 records could actually be constructed with matching `'subject'` - the rest of the records in either `d` or `e` had subjects which had no match in the other.

You only see the records that have the combined values from both dataframes, but only those that share the value for `'subject'`. Any non-matching `'subject'` records are left out, on either side (it's an 'inner' join).

Look at the documentation for the other variants. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html